# Why is my argument not being recognized when I use it inside the function

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

```
const notes = require('./getNotes')
// gets notes in Object format


// function to create new note
const createNote = ( noteTitle, message, notes) => {
  notes.noteTitle = message
  return notes
}


module.exports = createNote
```

I am having trouble understanding the reason that this code is not letting my pass in my own argument for the noteTitle. It is very frustrating. Could someone provide a basic explanation of why things are going wrong and what an alternative method might work well and why that method works in comparison to this one. Thanks!

Comment: I think that Haider helped my understand a little bit. I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation. I found out that to append a customer key: value pair onto the Object I could instead use  ---------------  notes[noteTitle] = message -------------------------- I'm still not entirely sure the difference but my best guess is that in the first way up above the noteTitle isnt't defined previously and in the second one, the syntax is setting up the noteTitle variable on the fly? I apologize. I'm just getting started learning without tutorials and this confused me a bit.

Answer (score 0):

scopes, the function body will replace the outside notes with the parameter, either give the notes constant a new name or the function parameter a new name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).